# How to delete an item in ReactJS when having multiple classes?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I found this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/315/ but what's different is that I'm trying to implement item deletion in a more complex architecture with class dependencies.

It may also be worth mentioning that item creation is working perfectly, but item deletion must be implemented differently (because I don't want all items to be deleted with a button, a button should only delete its respective item). I also have `deleteItem: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired` as a propType in each of my classes, but I'm not sure if this is correct.

So first I have my Item.jsx class's render and onDelte methods, where I render 'Items' including their 'Delete' (Eliminar) button:

```
    onDelete(item){
    e.preventDefault();
    deleteItem(item);
}
render(){
    const {item} = this.props;
    return(
        <li>
            <a onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}>
                {item.name}
            </a><br/>
            <a onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}>
                {item.price}
            </a><br/>
            <a onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}>
                {item.donation}
            </a><br/>
            <a onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}>
                {item.image}
            </a><br/>
            <form onSubmit = {this.onDelete.bind(this)}>
                <input type = "submit" value = "Eliminar"/>
            </form>
        </li>
    )
}
```

Then we have App.jsx's methods:

```
  deleteItem(item){
  const newState = this.state.items;
  if (newState.indexOf(item) > -1) {
     newState.splice(newState.indexOf(item), 1);
     this.setState({items: newState})
  }

  render(){
return(
  <ItemSection
    items = {this.state.items}
    addItem = {this.addItem.bind(this)}
    setItem = {this.setItem.bind(this)}
    deleteItem = {this.deleteItem.bind(this)}
  />
)
```

Then ItemForm and ItemList are classes imported by ItemSection. ItemSection renders a div of all of proptypes including deleteItem.

And finally here's ItemList's render method:

```
    render(){
    return(
        <ul>{
            this.props.items.map(itm =>{
                return <Item
                    item = {itm}
                    key = {itm.id}
                    setItem = {this.props.setItem}
                    deleteItem = {this.props.deleteItem}
                />
            })
        }</ul>
    )
}
```

What's happen when rendering the file is I'm getting an Uncaught Error (and can't read what it is because it immediately disappears in my developer console) and then the app reinitiates.

Answer (score 0):

When the form's onSubmit method is called, it firstly tries to submit the form the old fashioned way. Instead of defining your own method and preventing the default behaviour (in your code the first argument getting passed to deleteItem is the event, not the item), I suggest using just a button, as follows:

```
<button onClick = {() => this.props.deleteItem(this.props.item}>Submit</button>
```

If you don't want to, you can change the form onSubmit to something like this

```
<form onSubmit = {event => this.onDelete(event, item)}>
```

and onDelete method to

```
onDelete(e, item) {
  e.preventDefault();

  this.props.deleteItem(item):
}
```

Also as it has been mentioned, const newState = this.state.items returns just a reference, you can use the spread operator to get a new copy

```
const newState = { ...this.state.items }
```

Comment: Thanks! It's working fine. However, using the spread operator didn't make the thing work. newState should = this.state.items otherwise an error saying 'newState.indexOf is not a function'.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is probably with `deleteItem(item);` in your `item.jsx`. You need to say `this.props.deleteItem(item);`.

Also, in the same method, you are doing `e.preventDefault()` and `e` is not even passed. So pass `e` to your method to use it.

in this line `const newState = this.state.items;`, you are getting same reference to state instead of returning a new one for mutation as well as using const which is used for constants while you are mutating it in the same method. I would suggest doing `let newState = this.state.items.slice();` to get a fresh copy.

in here `newState.splice(newState.indexOf(item), 1);`, you could assign the index to a variable since you are using it twice in the method.